# Why this useEffect hook is running several times when app start loaded for the first time?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using redux for the state management for the app. In my app there is an `alert box` inside the useEffect hook which will call every time a value changes.

The problem is that when the app is loaded for the first time the `useEffect` hook is calling several times. So there is several `alertBox`

here is how my component looks like.

```
const Cart = ({navigation}) => {
  
  let cartList = useSelector((state) => state.productReducer.cartList);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn === false) {
      navigation.navigate('Home');
    }
    cartList = [];
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      async function fetchData() {
        setLoading(true);
        await dispatch(fetchCart(tokenData));
        setLoading(false);
      }
      fetchData();
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cartList?.OrderDTO?.Id === null) {

      ///////////////////////
      //calling several time on first load
      ///////////////////////

      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        Alert.alert(
          'Notification',
          'Your Cart is Empty',
          [{text: 'OK', onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Home')}],
          {cancelable: false},
        );
      } else {
        setModalVisible(true);
      }
    }
  }, [cartList]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCart(tokenData));
  }, [childState]);
```

The `dispatch(fetchCart()` function is use to load data from api.

Comment: is this happening on your home component?

Comment: @sathyareddy Yeah. The pop up start at cart screen. after the first navigation the alert still persist up to Home Screen

Comment: do you want it appear just once this component loads?

Comment: What is the childState ?